# Couldn't find GetRequestContext in System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am getting the following error while writing the below code -

Error

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestContext' and no extension method 'GetRequestContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code

```
var context = actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext();
context.Principal = principal;
```

I have referenced to the required library - System.Net.Http also but still the error is coming.

Comment: In Web API 2.0, there is a new HttpRequestContext class.  Try just using, `var context = Request.GetRequestContext();` in System.Web.Http.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to referencing the System.Net.Http assembly, make sure you bring the namespace in scope:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`
and then you can access extensions in `System.Net.Http` namespace such as  `request.GetRequestContext()`, etc.